# margin bottom in css with two vertical span elements

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am using ionic and wanted vertical span elements to have a certain distance between.

Here is a demo:

http://play.ionic.io/app/8682286f77a8

```
<ion-item class="item item-avatar icon-row">
  <img src="img/sale_icon.jpg">
  <span style="color:#078d00;font-size:22px; margin-bottom: 1opx"> {{ '36,000' }}</span>
  <br>
  <span style="color:#4b4b4b;font-size:18px"> Sale</span>
</ion-item>
```

However, `margin-bottom` is not working at all.

I could use another br between these spans and that works but it create more distance than I really want to.

What does really look wrong with it in above piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` to the `span`. It will make them respect the `margin-bottom` property.

```
<ion-item class="item item-avatar icon-row">
  <img src="img/sale_icon.jpg">
  <span style="color:#078d00;font-size:22px; margin-bottom: 10px;display:inline-block;"> {{ '36,000' }}</span>
  <br>
  <span style="color:#4b4b4b;font-size:18px;display:inline-block"> Sale</span>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display: inherit;` property to span. It will work. 
Plus, whenever you add some styling in ionic framework, don't forget to add `!important` with styling, because elements in ionic directives inherit styling from parent element.

Answer (score -1):

I've updated your code -

```
span {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

now `margin-bottom` works well!!

Full Code -

```
<ion-item class="item item-avatar icon-row">
  <img src="img/sale_icon.jpg">
  <span style="color:#078d00;font-size:22px; margin-bottom:10px;"> {{ '36,000' }}</span>
  <span style="color:#4b4b4b;font-size:18px;"> Sale</span>
</ion-item>

/* CSS */
span {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/c523b122a3cb), *with `display: list-item` you don't need to add `<br>` after the `span`.*